# modifiy and customize the behavior of the UINavigationBar back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a ViewController embeded in a navigationBar. I want the back button in the navigation bar to have the following effect :

- if a condition is fullfilled, apply the normal behavior of the back button
- if the condition is not fullfilled, stay  and remain on the same VC to do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
       let transparentButton = UIButton()
       transparentButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)
       transparentButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
       transparentButton.addTarget(self, action:"backAction:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(transparentButton)
    }
```

And the function is

```
 func backAction(sender:UIButton) {
     // check your condition
 }
```

Comment: thks just have to modify the action syntax  : action: #selector(backAction(sender:) great

Comment: and do you know the code i have to put in 'backAction' in order to perform the normal back of the navigation controller ?

Comment: Yes, just place your condition that you want to check, if it succeed then go back by self.navigationController.popViewController(animated : true) else do your custom task.

Comment: last question for my understanding : is the standard backbutton remaining under the custom one that you added ? Would it be "safer" or "cleaner" to remove the standard backbutton before adding the custom one as a subview ?

Comment: You can hide it, there is no issues in that.